# cvHoughCircles() parameters in JavaCV?

Tags: opencv, javacv

I want to find circles in an image by using cvHoughCircles() .
But I confused about the fourth parameter, because when I use "1", the cvHoughCircles() does not find circles and when I use "2", the method work properly and detect all circles in the image.

[Click Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43756115/Why.jpg) to see the screenshot of my program for both cases.

I did the same operation on another image ,but this time changing the value of the fourth parameter from 1 to 2, didn't affect the result[cvHoughCircles() returned the same result for both cases( using 1 or 2 for the value of the fourth parameter)] .

Can anyone please tell me what value should be sued for the fourth parameter when working with different images?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html

It lists the c/c++/python implementations for all the functions stating what each parameter does and i've always found that one of them is what javacv has been wrapping (in this case the c code). I was actually looking for this page when i came across your post so in case it happens again i can now follow my own link (awesome!). Now to answer your question as best I can.

The function looks like this:

```
CvSeq* cvHoughCircles(CvArr* image, void* circle_storage, int method, double dp, double min_dist, double param1=100, double param2=100, int min_radius=0, int max_radius=0 )
```

Where the site describes:

dp – Inverse ratio of the accumulator resolution to the image resolution. For example, if dp=1 , the accumulator has the same resolution as the input image. If dp=2 , the accumulator has half as big width and height.

I am *guessing* (based on what i remember from class) that what this refers to is the pyramid scheme that is sometimes used in feature detection. Basically you average the pixels of an image to get a smaller image in order to find the locations of important features like corners or in this case circles which in the end is based on gradient information (hence the black and white or greyscale image that should be used).

Using dp=1 should be perfectly fine however, just make sure to call cvSmooth() on the image so the gradient vectors make a nice circle around the circle. If you **know** that there is a circle then you could keep smoothing and dilating (cvDilate) until the circle appears but then you may detect artifacts so the biggest circle should be of what's interest. In the end it depends on the situation you are putting the algorithms through.